# Insert row into DB using radio button

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button, row

i need some help here.

I need to create this grid that allows the user to select a winner, and that winner will be stored into a table in my database.

Im geeting all done, until the point were i need to me this Radio Button working, it inserts an empty row.

This my form...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" .$row['id']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='premio' value='".$row['id']."'>" ."</td>";
  echo "<td >" .$row['nombre']. "</td>";
  echo "<td name='correo'>" . $row['correo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td name='telefono'>" . $row['telefono'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ar1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ar2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['br1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['br2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cr1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dr1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dr2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dr3'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['er1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['er2'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";


echo "<input type='submit' value='enviar'/>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</form>

</div>
```

And the link if you want to check it out.

http://www.gifted.cl/clientes/servier/registro_evento_1.php

php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO ganadoresevento (nombre,correo,telefono)
VALUES
('$_POST[nombre]','$_POST[correo]','$_POST[telefono]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Respuestas registradas";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see anything in your PHP for your radio button.

Comment: You aren't using any <input type="radio" /> for the other fields

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='premio' value='".$row['id']."'>" ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='nombre' value='".$row['nombre']."'>" ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='correo' value='".$row['correo']."'>" ."</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='radio' name='telefono' value='".$row['telefono']."'>" ."</td>";
```

Don't really know what inputs you want to use but this uses radio button.  You could use `<input type="text">` or `<input type="hidden">`

Have a look at prepared statement also http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php